# linkedin rest api : how am i to know if the invitation is sent?

Tags: php, linkedin-api, social-networking

Hi I am using Linkedin rest api to send invitation from my website. I have success fully send message from email. Now i am trying to send invitation via ID. WHat should i expect the response.

Please view my code:

```
       $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
        'format' => 'json',
       );


        $invite = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
        $invite .= '<mailbox-item>';
        $invite .= '<recipients>';
        $invite .= '<recipient>';
        $invite .= '<person path="/people/' . $arr['id'] . '" />';
        $invite .= '</recipient>';
        $invite .= '</recipients>';
        $invite .= '<subject>Invitation to Connect</subject>';
        $invite .= '<body>Test message for prajwol.. </body>';
        $invite .= '<item-content>';
        $invite .= '<invitation-request>';
        $invite .= '<connect-type>friend</connect-type>';
        $invite .= '<authorization>';
        $invite .= '<name>' . $arr['auth_name'] . '</name>';
        $invite .= '<value>' . $arr['auth_val'] . '</value>';
        $invite .= '</authorization>';
        $invite .= '</invitation-request>';
        $invite .= '</item-content>';
        $invite .= '</mailbox-item>';
```

And the Curl request is

```
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox?oauth2_access_token=' . Yii::app()->session['linkedin_credentials']['access_token'];
    // Tell streams to make a POST request

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $invite);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Where $arr is an associative array for eg.

```
    $arr = Array ( 
                   id => id=ffjIbK64ba, 
                   auth_name => OUT_OF_NETWORK, 
                   auth_val => mTvp 
                 );
```

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Linkedin's API documentation, you should be able to check wether your invitation or not with the HTTP code returned by the web server : https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/request-and-response-headers

To check it, set CURLOPT_HEADER to TRUE, and parse $result.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response.. i got 201 as reponse.. seems like I am doing it right :) thanks.